# Translating a text file from english to chinese using google translate api or other

Tags: google-translate

I need to translate a text file from english to chinese using google translate api, which programming language would be feasible to do so? Or is there any other approach to do so?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can interface with it very well. But I am not sure about an actual programming language.